# Model Data not loading on direct load of route

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I have an application that when following a `link-to` everything works as expected, but when navigating directly to a child route my model data doesn't seem to load.  In my child (types) route I am using `this.modelFor`in my model hook.  Here is a bin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oSApiSeh/7#/types/secondary navigating there directly doesn't show the colors, but if you click secondary it works.

Here is the source of that jsbin:

```
// ... groupBy definition omitted
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('colors', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.resource('types', { path: 'types/:type_group' }, function() {});
  });
});

App.ColorsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Color.find();
  }
});

App.TypesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor('colors').filterBy('type', params.type_group);
  }
});

App.ColorsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  grouped: _groupBy('type')
});

App.TypesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});

App.Color = Ember.Model.extend({
  'color':Ember.attr('string'),
  'type': Ember.attr('string')
});
App.Color.adapter = Ember.FixtureAdapter.create();
App.Color.FIXTURES = [
  { color:'red', type: 'primary'},
  { color:'green', type: 'primary'},
  { color: 'yellow', type: 'secondary'},
  { color: 'orange', type: 'secondary'},
  { color: 'blue', type: 'primary'}
];
```

My templates:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}

    I am wanting a route to .../primary that has red, green, and blue as its model and a route to .../secondary that has yellow and orange in its model
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="colors">
    <ul>
    {{#each grouped}}
      <li>{{#link-to 'types' group}}{{group}} ({{content.length}}){{/link-to}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="colors/index">
    all colors
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="types">
    Types
    <ul>
    {{#each item in controller}}
      <li>{{item.color}} </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ebryn helped me in IRC. The issue was/is promise related. Ember-Model uses `.fetch()` to return a promise. From that promise, we can call `.then()` and do `resolved.get('content')` and filter.

A working example can be seen here - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cawaq/3/edit

The changes were just to `TypesRoute` as shown below:

```
App.TypesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Color.fetch().then(function (items) {
      return items.get('content').filterBy('type', params.type_group);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call `modelFor` in your `App.TypesRoute`. When you enter the page 'normally', you end up in the `colors.index` route, which loads all colors into the store. However, when you enter directly into `types` or `types.index`, `modelFor` will return an empty array because the colors have not been loaded yet (it does not automatically fetch the model if not present).

The following unfortunately doesn't work either; I suspect because the model hook is not halted while the data is fetched.

```
App.TypesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Color.find().filterBy('type', params.type_group);
  }
});
```

I use Ember Data myself, so unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with Ember Model to propose a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I originally had this as an Ember Data solutions, but I am using Mongo as a backend and need the ability to do nested embedded objects, and Ember-Model seems like it has good support (I have the embedded stuff working).

Comment: You should use `App.Color.fetch()` instead of `find()` if you want a promise